# List not getting refreshed

Tags: android

I am trying to refresh my list view after deleting items from it, but i am not geting the desired result. The items are getting deleted when i reload the activity but not at the time i press the delete button. Here is my code:

```
public void deletelist()
{
    mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    for(int i=0;i<favtitle.size();i++)
    {
        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("train",favtitle.get(i));
        map.put("value",favloc.get(i));
        map.put("employer",favemp.get(i));

        mylist.add(map);
    }

    mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.listdelete,
            new String[] {"train","value","employer"}, new int[] {R.id.dept,R.id.jobloc,R.id.employer});
    lv.setAdapter(mSchedule);
    lv.setDividerHeight(2);
    lv.setCacheColorHint(Color.WHITE);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int position,long id)
        {

            String str3 = favtitle.get(position);
            db.delete("Favorites7","title= '"+str3+"'",null);

            db.close();
            //Data Base Select
            db = openOrCreateDatabase(
                    "ClassifiedAds.db"
                    , SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY
                    , null
            );

            db.setVersion(1);
            db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
            db.setLockingEnabled(true);

            //End-----
            cur= db.query("Favorites7", 
                    null, null, null, null, null, null);

            cur.moveToFirst();
            while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {

                favtitle.add(cur.getString(1));
                favloc.add(cur.getString(3));
                favemp.add(cur.getString(2));
                lat.add(cur.getString(7));
                log.add(cur.getString(8));

                cur.moveToNext();
            }

            cur.close();

            //mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
            HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            for(int i=0;i<favtitle.size();i++)
            {
                map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map.put("train",favtitle.get(i));
                System.out.println("==="+favtitle.get(i));
                map.put("value",favloc.get(i));
                System.out.println("==="+favloc.get(i));
                map.put("employer",favemp.get(i));
                System.out.println("==="+favemp.get(i));

                mylist.add(map);
            }

            mSchedule.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
            mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(Favorites.this, mylist, R.layout.listdelete,
                    new String[] {"train","value","employer"}, new int[] {R.id.dept,R.id.jobloc,R.id.employer});
            lv.setAdapter(mSchedule);
            lv.setDividerHeight(2);
            lv.setCacheColorHint(Color.WHITE);


        }
    });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use **notifyDataSetChanged()** method with the listview within the condition where you are deleting the record , just after deleting the record put the **listview.notifyDataSetChanged()** code.
hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Use in this way: **listview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();**

Comment: It is not taking the code...do you have any example.....of list view with notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: check this one:**((SimpleAdapter)l1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();** where l1 is the object of ListView .

Comment: try this `((SimpleAdapter)parent.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried [invalidateViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#invalidateViews%28%29), it will redrawn you list view.

Comment: i implemented that but still no success

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved. What i had to do was that whenever the arraylist was reloading i had to clear the previous one.
Like:

*array-list name*.clear();
before adding items into the hashmap.